# favourite contact fr0m contact db

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I want to retrieve all contact then put them in different arraylist based on whether it is starred or not.
I am trying to retreive all contact and do the display them separately on the basis of whether they are starred or not

```
  contactId=8333;
 Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHONETIC_NAME };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = ?";
    Cursor cur= mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection,
                new String[] {contactId}, null);
   if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst() && cur.getCount() > 0) {

int idIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);

int displayNameIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

int phoneticNameIndex = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHONETIC_NAME);

do {

    String id = cur.getString(idIndex);
    String name = cur.getString(displayNameIndex);
    String star=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.STARRED));
    String value=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED));

                        } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
```

The variable star is always null and on retrieving variable value it throws exception.

Can someone tell me how to know whetheer contact is starred or not after retrieving all the contact data?

Comment: My cursor has all data retrieved now after iterating through cursor i want to retrieve/know wheteher the contact is starred or not..like how i am retrieving name and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to request the `STARRED` column from the cursor, you should include it in the  `projection`.

Comment: No..i want to retrieve all contact then i wana know starred value. i.e. whether that contact is stared or not so i can put them in different group.Depending on whether it is stared or not.

Comment: You request the columns `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHONETIC_NAME` from the database - is the "starred" value included in one of the three columns?

Comment: you see my cursor has all data retreieved now after iterating through  cursor i want to retrieve/know wheteher the contact is starred or not..like how i am retreiving name and all.

Comment: `STARRED` is a boolean flag indicating whether the contact is starred or not. If you don't request this flag, SQL does not provide you with it - basic SQL understanding.

Comment: Understood what you are trying to say ..i am not mentioning starred flag in projection.

Answer (score 1):

I will go with Smutje answer, you need to add STARRED to projection, unless we wrongly understood your problem.

Comment: I know i can do that but then I will get only starred contacts but thats not what i want.i want to retrieve all contact then put them in different arraylist based on whether it is starred or not.

Comment: I am telling you to put STARRED field in projection not in selection. You will still get all your contacts. Or may be I wrongly understood.